# Change AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer's frame

Tags: objective-c, layout, camera, avfoundation

I want to make my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer object in mode fullscreen, so I changed videoGravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill but yet nothing happens.
please can anyone help me.

```
- (void) openCamera {
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    previewLayer.frame = self.liveCameraView.bounds;
    [self.liveCameraView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //

    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];  // use AVCaptureTorchModeOff to turn off
    [device unlockForConfiguration];

    //

    NSError *error = nil;

    deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    [session addInput:deviceInput];

    _stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    _videoOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    [session addOutput:_videoOutput];

    [session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];

}
```

Comment: What is the size of view you are using? You need to create that previewView as fullscreen

Comment: I'm using a UIView fullscreen mode.